# How to add custom Form Cms Block in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I followed this doc https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-block
And tried to create a form block instead of text image.
At the end the form is just not showing in preview.
Am I missing something some cache or something.

Comment: Did you also follow the steps this section? https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-block#block-preview - did you build the admin (`bin/build-administration.sh`) - do you see any Javascript errors when inserting the block?

Comment: Yes I figured out the issue was some npm permission error while the `bin/build-administration.sh` was running. Fixing it made it work Thanks :)